# Allow using ?. syntax in eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I used the ?. syntax in my code, but when I configure eslint into my project, they marked such constructions as a parsing error (Unexpected token)
`const currentFiles = folder?.files`

Here is my eslint configuration

```
{
    "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
    "plugins": ["prettier"],
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
      "import/no-unresolved": "off",
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
      "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": ["error", {
        "required": {
          "some": ["nesting", "id"]
        }
      }],
      "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": ["error", {
        "required": {
          "some": ["nesting", "id"]
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to configure linter somehow so it won't be any error anymore?

Comment: What react version? and how you created the project? CRA ? eslint version ? and code example ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Support of `?.` operator ([optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) has been added to ESLint [in version 7.5.0](https://eslint.org/blog/2020/07/eslint-v7.5.0-released):

> The default parser and built-in rules will support this syntax when
> you enable `parserOptions.ecmaVersion: 2020` in your configuration:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2020
    }
}
```